# How to hide sidebar in magento checkout page?

Tags: magento

I want to hide siderbar in magento checkout page. Any one can suggest me to how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be `display:none` in CSS, as the js in *opcheckout.js* will be interacting with the DOM elements in that div to update information via AJAX.